# Best practice of changing style of child element in React

Tags: css, reactjs

My parent class:

```
export default class Body extends Component<> {

    state = {
        isFilterPanelVisible: false
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        if(condition){
            this.setState({isFilterPanelVisible: true});
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <FilterPanel visibility={this.state.isFilterPanelVisible}></FilterPanel>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And my child class:

```
export default class FilterPanel extends Component<FilterPanelProps, FilterPanelState> {

constructor(props: FilterPanelProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        visibility: false
    }
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps: FilterPanelProps, prevState: FilterPanelState) {
        if(this.state.visibility !== this.props.visibility){
            this.setState({visibility: this.props.visibility})
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{visibility: this.state.visibility ? "visible" : "hidden"}}>FilterPanel</div>
        )
    }
}
```

At first my parent element does some actions and then update it's own state. Right away after updating the state rerender process starts and my parent class pass a new props to my child element. My child element updates his state and rerenders his components based on his new state (check 'visibility' state).

So my questions:

1. Are there some ways to simplify process of updating .css of child element? Which practice is the best? I think I used a lot of code for changing only one css style..
2. Can I escape using inline styles? I really dont think that it is good idea to add any .css to my .tsx files.